# Diagram Calculus for Spinors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, dg.differential-geometry

In quantum field theory class, we are doing spinors.  The representations of the Lorentz algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) = \mathfrak{su}(2) + i \mathfrak{su}(2)$ are indexed by two integers.  Then (1,2) and (2,1) are the left and right spinor representations, $\phi_a, \phi_{\dot{a}}$.

In the homework, we're asked to prove identities using spinor notation like $\psi\chi = \chi\psi$ and $(\psi\sigma^\mu\chi^\dagger)^\dagger = \chi\sigma^\mu\psi^\dagger$ by unsuppressing the indices (so $\psi \chi = \psi_a \chi^a$ and $\psi^\dagger \chi^\dagger = \psi^{\dagger\dot{a}} \chi_{\dagger\dot{a}}$.

I started developing "box" notation to keep track of which index is being matched/contracted with which other index in expressions like $ \epsilon^{ab}\epsilon^{\dot{a}\dot{b}}\sigma^\mu_{a \dot{a}}\sigma^{\nu}_{b\dot{b}} $.  Since these are anticommuting variables, such notation would have to remember order of multiplication.

I started coming up with nice ways to handle upper and lower indices with upward and downwoard pointing boxes, tricks for handing Dirac and Majorana spinors and Hermitian conjugates.  Has diagrammatic calculus for spinors already been built somewhere?? I think Penrose did such a thing for twistors.

Comment: You should look in "Birdtracks" by Cvitanovic if you have not done so already. If you are doing something different then I would be interested in seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I would like to see a convincing argument that these diagrammatic calculi are actually useful.  I'm serious: I'd love to be convinced that it makes sense to go down this path.

Comment: @Jose: have you seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25187/resources-for-graphical-languages-penrose-notation-feynman-diagrams-birdtra ?  

Comment: @Jose: diagrammatic calculations for tensors and spinors are not very far from diagrammatic calculations in more general categories, where they undeniably help in come computations.  I think Emily Peters uses them in her thesis, for example.  But you're a physicist, so certainly know how useful Feynman diagrams are.  Even if you're not trying to do a path integral, the diagrammatics lets you "see" various identities.

Comment: You can also look up my article http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1734
it has a diagram calculus for the representation/invariant theory of su_2, although I do not consider Fermionic anticommuting variables.

Comment: I think I agree with José. If one can write Wess and Bagger[1] without use of such diagrammatic calculi, then I think it's likely of little use. What I've found of most use is superfields.

[1] http://press.princeton.edu/titles/2149.html

Comment: @Jose & Kelly: I think what you said is an expression of personal taste rather than a statement on the usefulness of diagram calculus

Comment: @Everyone: I was not "dissing" diagrammatic techniques in general.  I'm well aware of their usefulness in quantum field theory and also in proving identities in braided categories,... I was merely expressing a desire to be convinced that in the restricted context of representation theory their use is advantageous.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if they're useful.  I'm just saying manipulating indexes are unpleasant and error-prone.  Also, I'm drawing diagrams for its own sake.  There are calculations I'm trying to execute.  The example I gave is in fact proportional to the $-2 \eta^{\mu \nu}$.  The solution I will turn in for that homework problem will involve index chasing b/c I don't have time to come up with a more insightful proof.

Comment: Oopss! I'm not drawing them for their own sake...